# Use ant design input components with validation rules outside of an antd form

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd, react-hook-form

I don't want to use the antd Form component, but I do want to use the data entry components and I want to capture their styling when certain rules like `required` are not satisfied.

I am using `react-hook-forms` right now and I wrap a form element like

```
<FormContext>

<Controller
        rules={{ required: 'Enter your name!' }}
        name="name"
        as={<Input />}
        placeholder="name"/>

</FormContext>
```

In this manner, the rule validation does not get run.

If I change this to :

```
<Controller
        rules={{ required: 'Enter your name!' }}
        name="name"
        as={<Input required />}
        placeholder="name"/>
```

I get the default required styling on submission and things work.

If I do something like this:

```
<Controller
        rules={[{ required:true }]}
        name="name"
        as={
<Form.Item >
<Input/>
<Form.Item>
}
        placeholder=" name"/>
```

My default values that I send with a form context provider don't get recognized and data added isn't being registered through the Form.Item

I want to use the antd styling for this component separate from importing any antd Form specific code. Is there a way?